# Jquery Mobile - Go to top of page on transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile when you do transitions to different pages is there a way to have the page its transitioning to show the top of the page? If the current page has a long list and you scroll down, then click to go to another page with the slide transition, then click back to the previous page it shows the middle of the page where you last were. I would like it to actually go back to the top of the page when going back. Is this possible?

Comment: What?! My pages never remember the scroll position when going back with the back button! My page annoyingly scrolls to the top, before transitioning to the next page. It drives me crazy that this hasn't been fixed yet, even in the newly released 1.3 version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on triggering the back button?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/#/demos/1.0b3/docs/api/methods.html

```
//scroll to Y 100px             
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

Or on triggering the active page:

```
if ($("#myPage").is(".ui-page-active")) { ... }
```

I additionally think this is a feature which is nice, the back button takes you back to the place you have been. You don't have to re-orientate yourself because you get back to the point you were, I think its a nice usability feature.